# Getting " 'Request' object has no attribute 'Name'" in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a web application in Flask, but I keep getting the error:
 `'Request' object has no attribute 'Name'` when sending data from a 'POST' form in my html. I have two submit buttons that I have to differentiate, and I wanted to do that by using their name, which I have previously done and it worked. This is the code from my HTML:

```
    <input type = "submit"  class="fadeIn second" value="Add this data." name = "add">
    <input type = "submit"  class="fadeIn second" value="Delete this data." name = "delete">
```

and this is where i am getting the error:
`if request.method == 'POST' and request.Name=="add":`
Can anyone help me out, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, a `Request` object does not have a "Name" attribute. You can access the `name` value with `request.form.get("add")`, for example.

See [here](https://overiq.com/flask-101/form-handling-in-flask/) for more examples.